# How to reset the APP orientation after taking a photo?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm creating an iOS Landscape app by flutter.
I used [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to allow the app to take pictures with the camera.

After launching the camera, I rotated the device vertically and took a picture.
Then closed the camera, the APP SCREEN is still in portrait.
My hope is to automatically return to the landscape when the camera is closed.

info.plist

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

dart

```
final XFile? file = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

```
// 1.[important]set all orientation
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);

// 2.pick image with camera
final XFile? file = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

// 3.set landscapeLeft and landscapeRight
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by adding the following after user finishes picking up image:

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your idea. The first time went well. But then I launched the camera again, and did the same test, this time it didn't work. The screen is still in portrait.